# Ubuntu 18.04 lightdm does not work properly

Tags: 18.04, login, lightdm, login-screen, gdm

I do not like `gdm` on Ubuntu 18.04 so I have replaced it with good old `lightdm` and `unity-greeter` with the following command:

```
sudo apt install lightdm unity-greeter
```

I've also selected `lightdm` in dialog menu during installation.

Now it appears to work partly:
When I reboot my computer `lightdm` is shown and I am able to login into my system.

But if I leave my computer alone and it locks automatically after 5 minutes or if I lock it with `Super + L` then `gdm` lock screen appears. How it can be fixed?

Comment: Is it possible that you should install `ubuntu-unity-desktop` as well?

Comment: I have posted a related question on https://askubuntu.com/q/1216934/446253 which deals with Unity/lightdm not going beyond the greeter/login page.

Comment: I do not think I need full de. During installation of greeter all recommends have been installed like sound indicator etc.

Comment: Do you still have that problem?

Comment: Yes. It was so annoying that I've switched back to gdm

Comment: See if https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/ and namely the part "How to install Unity on Ubuntu 18.04" helps you. In my case I did not round up the installation and select the final desktop environment right in the login page. I had missed this step while reading around and it made my selection of Unity stable. Perhaps it helps in your case too.